# Confuse with the linus conditions '-z' '-n'

Tags: linux, conditional-statements

here is my script：

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "para:" teatp

if [ -z $teatp ]; then
    echo '-z is ture'
else
    echo '-z is false'
fi

if [ -n $teatp ]; then
    echo '-n is ture'
else
    echo '-n is false'
fi
```

when I input nothing and press enter, the result is

```
para:
-z is ture
-n is ture
```

on the other hand, when I input something and press enter, the result is

```
para:qwer1234
-z is false
-n is ture
```

which confused me is the first result `-n is ture`. 
I think the `-n` and `-z` are antonyms, but why is the result the same?
There must be something I ignore or misunderstand.
I will be appreciate if someone can point out

Answer (score 0):

the **#testp** should be quote by double quotation marks?
like:

```
[ -n "$teatp" ]
```